# Next js renders quirky styles for bootstrap components after each refresh

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js

here is the problem:

when i open the page or hard refresh it loads all the components correctly except for some buttons and form controls from bootstrap 4 and it results in a quirky styled form and icons

I'm using Bootstrap 4 through a CDN link tag in _app.js instead of installing it from npm.

here is the undesired result
[image]

but when i resize the window in any way (maximizing or dragging) or when i do something results in a recompilation the correct styles suddenly gets loaded and everything is fine but any hard refresh will result in the same wrong styles again!

here is the correct styles after resizing the window

[image]

I've tried three popular browsers and i keep getting the same result.

does any one have any idea what is causing this and how to solve it? or is this behaviour persist in production!?

Comment: What happens of you don't use a CDN?

Comment: @Mickers do you mean if i don'y use CDN approach? then what should i use? is there any guaranteed approach that won't result in the same problem?!

Comment: I'm curious if the CDN link isn't loading as fast as your app does. As you stated if it recompiles it seems to fix the problem. Some companies don't allow the use of CDN's at all because it might break your codebase since the devs could make a change that you're not aware of. Just make a local copy of the exact version your app depends on and reference that.

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge about this, but how do i do that?

Comment: Download the zip from [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/) page. Extract the contents and place them inside the app then reference bootstrap.min.css instead of the CDN. You just need to reference where it is in your folder structure instead of the URL.

Comment: thanks i will make sure to try that later, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Could you try overriding `pages/_document.js`?

```js
import Document, {Head, Main, NextScript} from 'next/document';
import React from 'react';

class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
                    <meta content="IE=edge" httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
                    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

This will include the Bootstrap CSS file from the CDN with the initial request from the server.

Comment: implemented that but the problem still persists